# Move WordPress Database to RDS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, postgresql, amazon-rds

We have a working WordPress website that we use to help with business operations. We are getting to the point where we want to begin to scale our applications and use a more focused database service like RDS.

If you were to transition your wordpress database to RDS, how would you go about doing this? Would this cause a lot of problems?

Comment: RDS is just Amazon database service, so exporting the database from the current location and importing it to RDS will move the database then you should edit the wordpress config to point the new database location.

Comment: For scaling of WP, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

Answer (score 1):

Hello try to read this manual [Migrate Your Application Database To Amazon RDS](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/migrate-database-rds/) no problem at all.